# Suppose $V, $and $W$ are both finite dimensional . Prove that there exits an injective linear map from $V$ to $W$ if and only if $dimV \leq dim W.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are both finite dimensional. Prove that there exits an injective linear map from $V$ to $W$ if and only if $\dim V \leq \dim W$.

**Proof**: Suppose $V$ and $W$ are both finite dimensional. Then we have $\dim V = \dim(\text{null} (T)) + \dim (\text{range} (T))$. Then we have $\dim V= \dim \text{range} (T)\leq \dim W$.
So there exists an injective map, so that $\dim V \leq \dim W$.

Conversely, suppose $\dim V\leq \dim W$. Then let $\dim V = n, \dim W = m$. Define a basis for  $V$ by $v_1,\ldots,v_n $ for $V$ and $w_1,\ldots,w_m$ for $W$.
Can someone please help me? I dont really know how to show there is an injective linear map .

Comment: You can just show that there exists one, for example the one which maps $v_i$ to $w_i$.

Comment: Note: For "only if" you could show that the image of a basis of $V$ is linearly independent in $W$ using the injective property. (You haven't, incidentally, said what $T$ is).

Comment: $T$ can be defined as $T: V→W$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: define $T$ by $v_i\longmapsto w_i$, $i=1,\dots n$.

Comment: So if I define T as you say we have $T: V → W$ by $Tv_1 = w_1,...,Tv_n = w_n$. and $n \leq m.$ So $T(v_1,...,v_n) = a_1v_1 + ....+ a_nv_n$ and each $a_1v_1 + ...+ a_nv_n = 0 $ if and only if $(v_1,...,v_n) = (0,....,0)$ since $(v_1,...,v_n)$ is linearly independent , we have $null T = {\{0,...,0}\}$ so $T $ is one to one.  Can someone please verify this?

Comment: HI Martin , can you please give me some feedback? thanks

Comment: @user5956, right.

Comment: hi, your answer was very helpful! However i have a question (please excuse my limited knowledge) , can this be proved if T is not injective?

Comment: @MansiTyagi, *always* there is a linear $T:V\longrightarrow W$, namely...

Comment: Thank you! clear to me now!